# Cannot add MSCRM 2011 WCF service reference in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Tech Friends,

I could not add MSCRM 2011 WCF service reference in Visual Studio 2010. It throws error when try performing this action. How do we add this service as service reference in Visual Studio 2010 and generate all proxy classes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following these instrutions? [Download the Endpoints Using the Dynamics CRM Developer Resources Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309401.aspx).

Specifically in the "Using the WSDL" section.

> To add a service reference for these services to a Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2010 project, you must append ?WSDL to the service URL when
>   specifying the address in the Add Service Reference dialog box. For
>   example, the discovery service WSDL address is
>   `http://servername/xrmservices/2011/discovery.svc?wsdl.`

Comment: Hi, I have checked it earlier. It did not help. I get this error: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://dev.crm4.dynamics.com/XrmServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl'.

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution for the problem and I have tested it :)

To add discovery service and organization service as reference in Visual Studio we have to add query strings: ?wsdl=wsdl0

eg:-

.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?**wsdl=wsdl0**

The same applies for discovery service also.

Check this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/033f9831-5e88-4b85-a4eb-a55985f39997